# How can I get current value for MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to get current value which is ID number.
For my table, the ID has Auto_increment option and I would like to get the ID value.
In Oracle, it is like that:

```
    INSERT INTO mvc_board(bName, bTitle, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep,
bIndent) 
VALUES('abcd', 'is title', 'is content', 0, mvc_board_seq.currval, 0, 0);
```

However, I am using MariaDB so I used this query:

```
INSERT INTO mvc_board (bName, bTitle, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent)
VALUES ('pat', 'is title', 'is content', 0, SELECT MAX(bId) FROM mvc_board, 0, 0);
```

However, this has syntax error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mvc_board (bName, bTitle, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent)
SELECT 'pat', 'is title', 'is content', 0, MAX(bId), 0, 0 FROM mvc_board
```

Answer (score 1):

The next auto_increment value is available in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
INSERT INTO mvc_board (bName, bTitle, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent)
SELECT 'pat', 'is title', 'is content', 0, AUTO_INCREMENT, 0, 0 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = database() AND TABLE_NAME = 'mvc_board';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use mysql session variable. First store the max id in @last_insert_id then use this in your Query. Hope it help.

```
SET @last_insert_id := 0;

SELECT @last_insert_id := MAX(bId) FROM mvc_board;


INSERT INTO mvc_board (bName, bTitle, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent)
VALUES ('pat', 'is title', 'is content', 0, @last_insert_id, 0, 0);
```